# How to make Ajax request to the Rally Webhooks API? Is it CORS-enabled?

Tags: ajax, cors, rally

I'm having some difficulty getting a response with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from the Rally API when making an Ajax request with an API key. The documentation indicates that cross-origin should be allow and the header should be present if the withCredentials property is used in the request. If someone can shed some light on what's missing here it would be much appreciated.

**Edit**: It seems I'm mixing up documentation from the regular API and the webhooks API, which is a separate service. The question I actually need answered is CORS enabled on the webhooks API, and if so what is wrong the ajax called below:

```
var ajaxCallSettings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/pigeon/api/v2/webhook",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "ZSESSIONID": key
    },
    "xhrFields": {
        "withCredentials": true
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify(rallyWebhook)
};
```

Comment: To find out yourself if the `https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/pigeon/api/v2/webhook` endpoint is CORS-enabled, one way you can try is this: `curl -i -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://<your-app-origin>" -H "ZSESSIONID: <your-key>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/pigeon/api/v2/webhook`. If the response you get back from that doesn’t include at least the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, it means the API endpoint isn’t CORS-enabled, so you’re not going to be able to call it directly from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser.

Comment: The docs as https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/pigeon/docs/webhooks don’t give any indication that API is CORS-enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CORS is enabled for the webhooks service currently.  If this is a feature you'd like, please reach out to your sub admin or account representative to make an official feature request.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the reply!